# error converting iPython Notebook to PDF

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-14.04, tex

I have searched many related posts and not finding a solution. I am trying to convert an Ipython Notebook .ipynb file to PDF, using the command:

```
$ ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF BTNFWeatherStationplotter.ipynb
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, iPython 2.2.0, TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian), pandoc 1.12.2.1, and all other dependencies specified on the iPython Notebook installation docs.

I get the following error message:

```
(gen_sci)pwright@PJW:~/CSCI250_comp_science/snow_scraper/BTNFWeatherStationplotter_files [master] $ ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF BTNFWeatherStationplotter.ipynb
[NbConvertApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/pwright/.ipython/profile_default'
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook BTNFWeatherStationplotter.ipynb to latex
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in BTNFWeatherStationplotter_files/  
[NbConvertApp] Loaded template article.tplx
[NbConvertApp] Writing 74454 bytes to BTNFWeatherStationplotter.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF
[NbConvertApp] Running pdflatex 3 times: [u'pdflatex', u'BTNFWeatherStationplotter.tex']
[NbConvertApp] CRITICAL | pdflatex failed: [u'pdflatex', u'BTNFWeatherStationplotter.tex']
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
(./BTNFWeatherStationplotter.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grffile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(./BTNFWeatherStationplotter.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
 Add 3.73001pt and more to the right margin.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./BTNFWeatherStationplotter.out) (./BTNFWeatherStationplotter.out)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

! Argument of \@xverbatim has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.233 \end{verbatim}}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.233 \end{verbatim}}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on BTNFWeatherStationplotter.log.

[NbConvertApp] Removing temporary LaTeX files
```

I can get a PDF from html successfully using wkhtmltopdf, but I would like to see if the quality would be better using nbconvert.

Also, here is the output from my q.log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=latex   2014.8.18)  8 DEC 2014 22:34
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**q
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/q.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
File ignored
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> q

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6 strings out of 495033
 245 string characters out of 6181744
 45941 words of memory out of 5000000
 3315 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5i,0n,1p,81b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Is it possible that you provide the notebook, or at least a stripped down version of the notebook which still produces this error?

Comment: well, my notebook can be viewed [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/pjwright/snow_scraper_notebook/raw/b3550c23f30a7f235e213cc8b6bc62745c1f1dd5/BTNFWeatherStationplotter.ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually two issues with your first text cell (*"The following code accesses snow and..."*) 
[image]

1. You use a Heading 3 cell, hence this part is converted to a LaTeX subsubsection, which is very likely not what you want.
2. You have indented the text with 4 spaces which is the markdown syntax to create a verbatim environment.
   Verbatim environments are not allowed in latex headings, so this has to be changed as well.

If you insist on the heading style in the notebook you could use `<h3>` html tags to mark your first paragraph (but without the 4 space indent). However, these tags will be removed during the conversion to pdf - the text will be plain latex.

If you want to highlight the first paragraph in the notebook and the pdf you can use boldface characters. The necessary markdown syntax is `**foo**`. This markdown survives the conversion to latex.